# Counting triangle algorithm

Tags: visual, algorithm, counting

There is a type of puzzle where one needs to count triangles in a figure, generally a large triangle full of lines which create smaller ones.

[One example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9cxM_DQMXI)

Is there, or can someone develop ;), an algorithm to answer this?

Feel free suggesting and making up data representations for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396570/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-for-counting-the-number-of-triangles-in-a-graph).

Everything rests on seeing that the problem you are describing is a graph problem. So, everything should begin with expressing your shape as a graph. There is an [implementation in C](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/wap-to-find-number-of-triangle-in-given.html) which gives an example of the representation as a graph and which performs the task of calculating how many triangles there are.

Someone pointed at [this paper](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/cla/tria-mmult.pdf), saying that the problem is computationally as difficult as Matrix Multiplication. Essentially the time complexity will be $O(n^3)$.

One of the answers there by [evhen13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153791/evhen14) outlines the following candidate algorithm which is recursive in nature:

> You will need depth first search. The algorithm will be:
>
> 1) For the current node ask all unvisited adjacent nodes
>
> 2) for each of those nodes run depth two check to see if a node at depth 2 is your current node from step one
>
> 3) mark current node as visited
>
> 4) on make each unvisited adjacent node your current node (1 by 1) and run the same algorithm

Comment: Certain regular configurations do have special formulas. But this isn't true for a general configuration.

Comment: Which formula are you referring to? Do you mean that C implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force algorithm in pseudo code:

Assumptions: we have the set of all the vertices $V$ (where two or more lines meet) and lines (edges in graph theory) between them.

```
For each vertex a in V
  For each vertex b in V where b != a
    For each vertex c in V where c != a or b
      If there are lines connecting a<-->b, b<-->c, and c<-->a
      and if these vertices are not all in a straight line, then they
      form a triangle, so increment the triangle count
```

This is trivially $O(n^3)$.

There are some ways to prune this search by:

- Checking if $a$ and $b$ are connected by a line before selecting $c$
- Looping over the lines (edges) instead of the vertices might be more efficient, but not as intuitive